# Wrong Output Value when updating a variable using the Slider in GNU Radio

Tags: python, slider, gnu, difference, gnuradio

I am calculating the phase difference between two sine waves using GNU Radio using the following program:

[image: Phase Differnece - GNU Radio]

A slider is being used to change the phase difference. The initial value is set to be 90, and hence I see a 90° phase shift using the time sink block.

[image: Initial Phase Shift]

However, if this value is changed using the slider, I get the wrong output:

[image: Phase shift using the slider]

So every time the value is manually changed, without using the slider, the program works fine. However, if the value is changed using the slider while the program is running, I get the wrong output.

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: In what way is it wrong? What did you set with the slider when you got that ca -120 visualization?

Comment: The slider is set to 45. The output is -123, when it should be 45. This is what I don't understand... Why isn't the output at 45?